# The height of a general complete binary tree

Tags: discrete-mathematics

there's this weird question in my book that I cant seem to grasp.

Q:
Let $T = (V,E)$ be a complete binary tree and $|V| = n$. What is the maximum height of $T$?

Now, the textbook says that it is $\frac{n-1}{2}$, but whenever I try to apply that formula to another complete binary tree, it does not give me the max height that $T$ can be. How come it doesn't work, isn't this formula supposed to be applicable to all complete binary trees?

Comment: @copper.hat: given the formula in the OP, and that he mentions a "maximum height", I think that the definition of "complete" here is "every internal node has 2 children".

Comment: To the OP: can you edit your question and give us an example where you think this formula fails?

Comment: @FPE: Thanks, I see what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

Following @FPE's comment above, I am presuming that a binary tree is complete **iff** each node is either a leaf or an internal node with exactly 2 children.

Then the claim is that the maximum depth is $d_\max={n-1 \over 2}$.

First note that the number of nodes must be odd. To see this, first note that any sub-tree is also complete.
It is clear that if the tree has depth 0, then it must have a single node. So, suppose that any complete tree of depth $0,...,d$ has an odd number of nodes, and consider a complete tree of depth $d+1$. The number of nodes in the tree is one plus the number of nodes in the left and right sub-trees. Since the number of nodes in the left and right sub-trees is are odd, their sum is even and hence the tree has an odd number of nodes.

It is straightforward to construct a complete tree of depth ${n-1 \over 2}$ using $n$ nodes as follows: If $n=1$ then there is nothing to do. If $n\ge 3$ (and odd, of course), choose one node as the root, assign one left node to the right and build a complete tree of depth $n-2$ to the left. It is straightforward to see that the depth is ${ n -1 \over 2}$. Hence
$d_\max \ge { n -1 \over 2}$.

Now suppose we have a complete tree with $n$ (odd) nodes. If $n=1$ we have nothing to prove, so suppose $n \ge 3$, and suppose we have a path from the root $n_0$ to any leaf $n_d$ given by $(n_0,n_1,...,n_d)$. Since each of the nodes $n_0,...,n_{d-1}$ is internal, each must have at least one node on the other side, and so we must have at least $2d+1$ nodes. Since $n \ge 2 d +1$, we see that the depth of the leaf satisfies $d \le { n-1 \over 2}$. It follows that $d_\max \le { n-1 \over 2}$.